# unable to add select fields by giving values to input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

Hello guys hope you doing well.
The problem is...

1. I have one input field when you try to add some value there then one select box will appear.
   but the problem is it is showing only one I am not getting as per the values requirement.
2. the second problem is I am trying to use select field instead of input field i had tried

   `var e = document.getElementById("this_is_my_select_field_values");`

this one was for option but unable to use select field instead of input field.
`var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;`

here is my code :

```js
function addFields() {
 var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
 var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

 //Create array of options to be added
 var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"];

 while (myDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
  myDiv.removeChild(myDiv.lastChild);
 }
 for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));

  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
  selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
   option.text = array[i];
   selectList.appendChild(option);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- <div id="myDiv" class="col-xs-1">Append here</div> -->
      <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="" onkeyup="addFields()">
      <div id="myDiv" class="col-xs-1">Append here</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

First problem :: doesn't appearing number of select field.

Second problem :: it is not working while trying to use select field instead of input field where we are trying to put some values to appear select fields.
i had tried the following, but doesn't work.

```
<select id="id">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

please help guys. thanks in advance

Comment: it is because `i` is updated in inner `for loop`

Comment: ohhh sorry didn't seen that. yead it work thanks secret super star. but how can be possible to use select filed instead of input field?

Comment: you mean to take input to addfields (dropdowns)?

Comment: i means i want to use select field instead of input field. where we giving values to display select field. i just want to give there select field and because of the option add or display child select fields.

Comment: if you are using `jquery` you can use `$("#this_is_my_select_field_values").val();`

Comment: where is **this_is_my_select_field_values** defined?

Comment: i had tried but didnt worked can you please make changes into the input field to select field it is possible. please

Comment: this_is_my_select_field_values i removed this because of didn't worked.

Comment: i just want there this. <select id="member" name="member" value="" onkeyup="addFields()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      </select> than this. <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="" onkeyup="addFields()">

Comment: you can use `onchange` event for `select` not `onkeyup`

Comment: Added code as an example

Comment: not working. can i give my code again

Comment: check my updated answer. Below given example with select box. But I suggest you to use `jquery` than plain javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code like below:

change is

```
for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", array[j]);
            option.text = array[j];
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
```

```js
function addFields() {
 var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
 var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

 //Create array of options to be added
 var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"];

 while (myDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
  myDiv.removeChild(myDiv.lastChild);
 }
 for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));

  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
  selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

  //Create and append the options
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.setAttribute("value", array[j]);
   option.text = array[j];
   selectList.appendChild(option);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- <div id="myDiv" class="col-xs-1">Append here</div> -->
      <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="" onkeyup="addFields()">
      <div id="myDiv" class="col-xs-1">Append here</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

With respect to problem 2:

in plain java script:

```
var e = document.getElementById("elementId");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

using `jQuery`

```
var selected = ("#this_is_my_select_field_values").val();
```

Changing `input` to `select`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
   function addFields() {
 var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
 var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

 //Create array of options to be added
 var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"];

 while (myDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
  myDiv.removeChild(myDiv.lastChild);
 }
 for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));

  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
  selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

  //Create and append the options
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.setAttribute("value", array[j]);
   option.text = array[j];
   selectList.appendChild(option);
  }
 }
}
   </script>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- <div id="myDiv" class="col-xs-1">Append here</div> -->
    <select id="member" name="member" value="" onchange="addFields()"> <option value="">--select--</option><option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> </select>
      <div id="myDiv" class="col-xs-1">Append here</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that what i was expecting